# An irresistible inequality

Tags: real-analysis

The following occurred while working on some research project. Since the methods of proof I used were lengthy, I wish to see a skillful or insightful approach (perhaps even conceptual). Anyhow, here it is. Let 
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x+1}{e^{x+1}+1}\right)^2.$$
Can one give a short and elegant proof of these statements?

(1) $f(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function of $x$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

(2) In fact, the statement holds true if $e$ is replaced by any real number $t>1$.

Comment: I do not understand. Is this a problem or a challenge? In the second case, please note that MO is devoted to *questions*, and that challenges are not well-received here.

Comment: The last sentence makes it sound like you already know this to be true.  If so, then it's not really a question for this site.  It certainly may still be interesting and worth sharing, but in a paper / preprint / blog / problems column instead.

Comment: Perhaps you have confused us with that other place http://math.stackexchange.com , where problems with known answer are sometimes allowed.

Comment: In order to find a "short and elegant proof", it could be useful to know the OP's strategy of proof.

Comment: The OP's strategy involved piecing together inequalities and some asymptotics, etc. Not neat. Hence, the reason why the question is raised here. I look forward to a method which could complement or better that of Fedor Petrov. By the way, it would be nice to let go of the "hold".

Comment: Okay, it seems clear after the last comment and edit this is not meant as a "challenge", any more than any other question. At least not in the sense of "I have a wonderful proof; can you match it?" Rather, OP is dissatisfied with his/her solution and wants to know if one can improve on it. So I will vote to reopen, but of course we don't know if we can do better without some idea of that solution. So I'd like to ask the OP to furnish more details of the solution at hand.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know wether this helps you or not, but you may do as follows.

Denote $f(x)=(e^x-1)/x$. Note that $f'(x)=\frac{fe^x(x-1+e^{-x})}{x(e^x-1)}>0$, so
$f$ is a positive increasing function.

Lemma. The function $1/f=x/(e^x-1)$ is a (positive decreasing) convex function.

Proof. 
$$
(1/f)''=\frac{e^x(2+x-(2-x)e^x)}{(e^x-1)^3},
$$
we have to check that it is non-negative. If $x\geqslant 2$, this is clear.
If $0<x<2$, this reduces to 
$$
e^x\leqslant \frac{2+x}{2-x}=1+x+x^2/2+x^3/2^2+x^4/2^3+\dots,\,\,(1)
$$
that holds coefficient-wise: $n!\geqslant 2^{n-1}$ for $n\geqslant 1$.
Finally, the case $x<0$ reduces to $x>0$, since $2+x-(2-x)e^x$ and
$2-x-(2+x)e^{-x}$ always have opposite signs.

Corollary. $g:=1/f^2=x^2/(e^x-1)^2$ is convex.

Proof. $-(1/f^2)'=2(-1/f)'(1/f)$, both multiples are positive decreasing functions,
thus their product also decreases.

Now we claim that $g(x-a)+x^2/(e^x+1)^2$ decreases for each $a\geqslant 0$,
for $a=1$ we get your statement (and for other $a$ something equivalent to your remark).
Since $g'$ increases, we have $g'(x-a)\leqslant g'(x)$, so it suffices to check this for $a=0$.
We have $g(x)+x^2/(e^x+1)^2=2x^2(e^{2x}+1)/(e^{2x}-1)^2$. Denote $2x=y$,
we need to check that $y^2(e^y+1)/(e^y-1)^2$ decreases. Taking logarithmic derivative,
this is equivalent to $$\frac{2}x+\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}-\frac{2e^x}{e^x-1}\leqslant 0.$$
For $x=-y>0$ we have $$\frac2{y}-\frac2{e^y-1}\geqslant \frac2y-\frac2{y+y^2/2}=\frac1{1+y/2}>\frac1{1+e^y}$$
as desired. For $x>0$ we have 
$$
\frac{2}x+\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}-\frac{2e^x}{e^x-1}\leqslant \frac{2+x}x-\frac{2e^x}{e^x-1}=
\frac{(2-x)e^x-(2+x)}{x(e^x-1)}\leqslant 0
$$
by (1).

Comment: The second summand is not decreasing.

Comment: Oh, it is plus in denominator, not minus. Sorry.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, one should not answer off-topic questions (for instance, in order not to encourage them).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi sorry, this text was written before the question became officially considered an off-topic, or simultaneously. If you find it reasonable, I may remove it and send to OP elsewhere (I know him personally). I think, if the question is supposed to mean something like 'please explain this fact arising in my research with a short and elegant argument', it is suitable on MO, there are many such questions.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: well, the way in which the question is asked (for instance, the imperative tone and the last remark) gives the impression that it is a challenge for the MO users, and this kind of questions are surely non-acceptable here. Rewording the question in the sense you suggest might be a possibility.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: very nice argument, thanks. Will see how to adopt this to the case (2), e replaced by t, or someone else does. I'm also curious if there is any other approach.

Comment: If you replace $e$ to $t=e^a$, then multiply by $a^2$ and denote $ax+a=y$, you get $g(y-a)+y^2/(e^y+1)^2$.